# Fetch only first N lines of a Stack Trace

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

I have a Factory method that returns an object from a ID call.

Mock code:

```
public static Object getById(String id) {
    Object o = CRUD.doRecovery(Class, id);
    if(o == null) {
         printLogMessage("recovery by ID returned Null: " + id);
         // would really like to show only a few lines of stack trace.
    }
    return o;
}
```

How can I show only the first N lines of the stack trace (so I know the caller of the method) without dumping the whole stack trace on the log or having to rely on external libs?

Comment: Please don't use stack traces to get to know the caller of a method. It's very expensive (compare [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions) which also has some profiling data.). Rather use a second parameter and require your callers by contract to use some meaningful self-identifying ID.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming from what you are asking, that you don't have an exception to deal with. In which case you can get the current stack trace from:

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

This will tell you pretty much everything you need to know about where you've come from in the code.

Comment: Most comprehensive answer for the non-exception use case asked for in the question. Just output the first couple of elements of the "elements" array in a format convenient for you.

A word of warning tho, Stacktraces are **exceptionally** expensive to compute. You are looking at worsened performances in 4 orders of magnitude. Do not use this for high performance functions! Do your profiling, then put that idea in the bin and pass some identifier as parameter. Each caller then has to use some kind of self-id-ing argument for that method call by contract. Not as convenient, but much much faster.

Comment: Performance is not an issue, because we are treating logical exceptions, for example when some section of the app reference an Entity ID that does not exist. Then we can nail down the offender. I think that having the caller identify itself is an added layer of coupling I would rather pay out with performance.

Comment: But mikea's answer is very elegant, I am greening it.

Comment: The innermost method calls are at index 0, main is at index length-1. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262340/1048186) for an example of reproducing a stack trace (if you happen to have the full exception object).

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `ex.getStackTrace()` to get the stack elements, the `StackTraceElement` contains one line of the full stacks, then print print what ever you want.

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = ex.getStackTrace();
print(elements[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to truncate the stack trace, you can print the entire stack trace to a StringWriter then remove what you don't want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    try {
        throw new Exception("Argh!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(shortenedStackTrace(e, 1));
    }
}

public static String shortenedStackTrace(Exception e, int maxLines) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
    String[] lines = writer.toString().split("\n");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(lines.length, maxLines); i++) {
        sb.append(lines[i]).append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Alternatively, use `e.getStackTrace()` to obtain a `StackTraceElement[]` array. This gives you the caller stack (from inner to outer), but not the error message. You'll have to use `e.getMessage()` to get the error message.

Some logging frameworks can be configured to truncate stack traces automatically. E.g. see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263741/log4j-formatting-is-it-possible-to-truncate-stacktraces) about log4j configuration.

If you just want to see the stack trace at any point in the code, you can get the elements from the `Thread.currentThread()` object:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Comment: "Without having to rely on external libs"

Answer (score 3):

This method displays `i` lines of the stack trace, skipping the first two.

```
public static String traceCaller(Exception ex, int i) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ex.printStackTrace(pw);
    String ss = sw.toString();
    String[] splitted = ss.split("\n");
    sb.append("\n");
    if(splitted.length > 2 + i) {
        for(int x = 2; x < i+2; x++) {
            sb.append(splitted[x].trim());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return "Trace too Short.";
}
```

The first two lines are the exception name and the method that called `traceCaller()`. Tweak it if you want to show these lines.

Thanks go to @[BrianAgnew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12960/brian-agnew) ([stackoverflow.com/a/1149712/1532705](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1149712/1532705)) for the StringWriter PrintWriter idea

Comment: Thanks go to @BrianAgnew (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1149712/1532705) for the `StringWriter` `PrintWriter` idea.

Comment: IMO you should move this comment as part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Guava could help. For example we want to see only first ten rows:

```
log.error("Error:", Joiner.on("\n").join(Iterables.limit(asList(ex.getStackTrace()), 10)));
```

Comment: its should be  `Joiner.on("\n").join(Iterables.limit(Arrays.asList(ex.getStackTrace()), 10))`

Answer (score 1):

For an abbreviated version of e.printStackTrace():

```
        Exception e = ...
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        StackTraceElement[] elements = e.getStackTrace();
        for(int i = 0; i<elements.length && i < STACK_TRACE_LIMIT; i++) {
            System.out.println("\tat "+elements[i]);
        }
```

Replace `STACK_TRACE_LIMIT` with the limit you want or remove `&& i < STACK_TRACE_LIMIT` to reproduce the output of a simple stack trace (e.g., no nested exceptions)

The innermost method calls are at index 0, main is at index length-1.

Answer (score 0):

exemple to display the fifth first lines:

```java
        final int nbLinesToShow = 5;
        try {
            /* your code here */
        } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
            // catch error
            final StackTraceElement[] elements = e.getStackTrace();
            System.err.println(
                    "===================================== \n" + "[ERROR] lorem ipsum");
            for (int i = 0; i < nbLinesToShow; i++) {
                System.err.println(elements[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: No exception is thrown in the posed question; hence this is not an answer to the given question.

Answer (score -1):

Snippet in below link works for N lines.

Below snippet helps to strip off exception stacktrace.

```
public class LoggerHelper {

private static final String SEPARATOR = "\r\n";
private static final String CAUSE_CAPTION = "Caused by: ";
private static final String SUPPRESSED_CAPTION = "Suppressed: ";

/**
 * The first 10 lines of exception stack information are returned by default
 *
 * @param e
 * @return
 */
public static String printTop10StackTrace(Throwable e) {
    if (e == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return printStackTrace(e, 20);
}

public static String printStackTrace(Throwable e, int maxLineCount) {
    if (e == null || maxLineCount <= 0) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maxLineCount * 10);
    sb.append(e.toString()).append(SEPARATOR);
    StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
    if (trace == null) {
        return e.toString();
    }
    int count = maxLineCount > trace.length ? trace.length : maxLineCount;
    int framesInCommon = trace.length - count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sb.append("\tat ").append(trace[i]).append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    if (framesInCommon != 0) {
        sb.append("\t... ").append(framesInCommon).append(" more").append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    // Print suppressed exceptions, if any
    Throwable[] suppressedExceptions = e.getSuppressed();
    if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(suppressedExceptions)) {
        for (Throwable suppressedException : suppressedExceptions) {
            sb.append(printEnclosedStackTrace(suppressedException, maxLineCount, trace, SUPPRESSED_CAPTION, "\t"));
        }
    }
    // Print cause, if any
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause != null) {
        sb.append(printEnclosedStackTrace(cause, maxLineCount, trace, CAUSE_CAPTION, ""));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static String printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable e, int maxLineCount, StackTraceElement[] enclosingTrace,
                                              String caption, String prefix) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maxLineCount * 5);
    StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
    int m = trace.length - 1;
    int n = enclosingTrace.length - 1;
    while (m >= 0 && n >= 0 && trace[m].equals(enclosingTrace[n])) {
        m--;
        n--;
    }
    int count = maxLineCount > (m + 1) ? (m + 1) : maxLineCount;
    int framesInCommon = trace.length - count;
    // Print our stack trace
    sb.append(prefix).append(caption).append(e.toString()).append(SEPARATOR);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sb.append(prefix).append("\tat ").append(trace[i]).append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    if (framesInCommon != 0) {
        sb.append(prefix).append("\t... ").append(framesInCommon).append(" more").append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    // Print suppressed exceptions, if any
    Throwable[] suppressedExceptions = e.getSuppressed();
    if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(suppressedExceptions)) {
        for (Throwable suppressedException : suppressedExceptions) {
            sb.append(printEnclosedStackTrace(suppressedException, maxLineCount, trace, SUPPRESSED_CAPTION, prefix + "\t"));
        }
    }
    // Print cause, if any
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause != null) {
        sb.append(printEnclosedStackTrace(cause, maxLineCount, trace, CAUSE_CAPTION, prefix));
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

}

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)