# Configure Java installation to print only the first few lines of stack trace

Tags: java, logging, configuration, stack-trace

How can I configure the default java stack trace printing behaviour so only the head is visible? Currently I use `2>&1 | head` or `| less -i` and I find it suboptimal.

When having an uncaught exception, Java prints me 115 lines and then the text `... 102 more`. 99% to 97% of this trace is irrelevant to me. This leaves the first 3 lines interesting.

How can I configure Java to print me 2 lines and then, in my example case, `... 215 more`?

Comment: you could convert your stack trace to a string ([this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string) might help) and take a substring of this string, but I have this feeling this is not optimal either...

Comment: As [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706722/fetch-only-first-n-lines-of-a-stack-trace) pointed out, you want to get the array for the stack trace, and then subset that for the rows you want to see.

Comment: You wrote `uncaught exception`. I guess you have no control over the statcktrace at that point. Am I right?

Comment: @SubOptimal yes you are right

Comment: @naxa Do you want to change Java's default stack printing behavior throughout your entire application, or only in area?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for my entire application would be good for me currently. (That said I can imagine future readers looking for the other one too...)

Answer (score 5):

You can specify JVM parameter `MaxJavaStackTraceDepth`:

```
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=2
```

You can set this parameter in your run script. If you use IDE, there's a VM options or VM arguments field in a run configuration dialog. You can set the above parameter in the field.

For more detail, please refer to http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.kr/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html#MaxJavaStackTraceDepth

Comment: The list can be obtained with `java -XX:+PrintFlagsInitial`.