# Log4j2 formatting: Is it possible to truncate a particular StackTrace?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

i was wondering whether it is possible or not to log the first line of a particular exception in my program (ex DataAccessException). 
According to [Log4j formatting: Is it possible to truncate stacktraces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263741/log4j-formatting-is-it-possible-to-truncate-stacktraces) we can truncate exceptions. Is it possible to apply this restriction to only one exception, using log4j2?

Thanks in advance.